# Don't get all rostopic echo data

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node which publishes data 3 times.  But when I look at the results of the rostopic echo, I only get the last two cycles.  I have tried this with different counts, but rostopic echo always misses the first cycle.

```
std_msgs::Int16MultiArray head;  
ros::init(argc,argv, "xxxxxx");  
ros::NodeHandle nh;  
pubheader=nh.advertise<std_msgs>::Int16MultiArray>("Audio_head",1);  
ros::Rate loop_rate(1);  
int i,j;  
for(j=0;j<3;j++)  
{  
  head.data.clear();  
  for(i=0;i < headersize;i++)  
   {  
    head.data.push_back(header.ROSheader[i]);  
  }  
  pubheader.publish(head);  
  ros::spinOnce();  
  loop_rate.sleep();  
}
```

Any reason that only the last two instances are echoed?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260653/don%27t-get-all-rostopic-echo-data/) by [Bob H](https://answers.ros.org/users/30141/bob-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Archhaskeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/29156/archhaskeller/) on 2017-04-28**:
did you run rostopic echo before the node?

**Comment by [Bob H](https://answers.ros.org/users/30141/bob-h/) on 2017-04-29**:
Yes, I had rostopic running before running the node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A bit of a guess, but setting up subscriptions takes time, even if you only have everything running on a single machine.

As @Archhaskeller hints at, `rostopic` might simply be 'too late' to receive all publications.

If receiving *all* messages is important, consider using an interaction pattern that is not so completely decoupled as pub-sub (ie: services or actions), or see if a latched topic helps.

Another option might be to wait with publishing until there is (are) at least one (or more) subscriber(s). You can do that with checking [ros::Publisher::getNumSubscribers()](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html#ad56c8e954020290dcb87cd6bbd330a2b).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1